# Mirroring a website and maintaining URL structure

Tags: wget, mirroring

### The goal

I want to mirror a website, such that I can host the static files anywhere (localhost, S3, etc.) and the URLs will appear just like the original to the end user.

### The command

This is almost perfect for my needs (...but not quite):

```
wget --mirror -nH -np -p -k -E -e robots=off http://mysite
```

### What this does do

- `--mirror` : Recursively download the entire site
- `-p` : Download all necessary page requisites
- `-k` : Convert the URL's to relative paths so I can host them anywhere

### What this doesn't do

- Prevent duplicate downloads
- Maintain (exactly) the same URL structure

### The problem

Some things are being downloaded more than once, which results in `myfile.html` and `myfile.1.html`. This wouldn't be bad, except that when wget rewrites the hyperlinks, it is writing it with the `myfile.1.html` version, which is changing the URLs and therefore has SEO considerations (Google will index ugly looking URL's).

The `-nc` option would prevent this, but as of wget-v1.13, I cannot use `-k` and `-nc` at the same time. Details for this are [here](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?31781).

### Help?!

I was hoping to use wget, but I am now considering looking into using another tool, like httrack, but I don't have any experience with that yet.

Any ideas on how to achieve this (with wget, httrack or anything else) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just log in via ftp and download it

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible because the site is dynamically generated. I would like to dump a static version of this dynamic site.

Comment: Oh I see, apologies for the brain freeze

Comment: How are you getting two of `myfile.html`? Are they located under different paths, but `wget` is ignoring that and dumping them all in the same directory?

Comment: TBH, I haven't traced down exactly where they are coming from, I just know it's happening and I need to fix it.
The site is quite large so I'm assuming there are lots of references to any given page. Under which conditions a duplicate is created, I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`httrack` got me most of the way, the only URL mangling it did was make the links to point to `/folder/index.html` instead of `/folder/`.

Using either `httrack` or `wget` didn't seem to result in perfect URL structure, so we ended up writing a little bash script that runs the crawler, followed by `sed` to clean up some of the URLS (crop the `index.html` from links, replace `bla.1.html` with `bla.html`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[wget description and help](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm)

According to this (and a quick experiment of my own) you should have no problems using -nc and -k options together to gather the pages you are after.

What will cause an issue is using -N with -nc (Does not work at all, incompatible) so you won't be able to compare files by timestamp and still no-clobber them, and with the --mirror option you are including -N inherently.

Rather than use --mirror try instead replacing it with "-r -l inf" which will enable recursive downloading to an infinite level but still allow your other options to work.

An example, based on your original:

```
wget -r -l inf -k -nc -nH -p -E -e robots=off http://yoursite
```

Notes: I would suggest using -w 5 --random-wait --limit-rate=200k in order to avoid DOSing the server and be a little less rude, but obviously up to you.

Generally speaking I try to avoid using option groupings like --mirror because of conflicts like this being harder to trace.

I know this is an answer to a very old question but I think it should be addressed - wget is a new command for  me but so far proving to be invaluable and I would hope others would feel the same.